# javascript - video play not working in setInterval

Tags: javascript, video

I am trying to play video using .play(). 
This is for in app with mraid, only native javascript.

I'm trying to play a video with .play(), it works only when the video is loaded.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.play();
```

the above simple 2 lines works like a charm, only when the video is loaded.

Therefore i have to make sure the video is loaded by using setInterval

```
        var autoplay = setInterval(function(){
            var video = document.getElementById('extVideo-tab1');
            if(video !== null)
            {
                video.play();
                clearInterval(autoplay);
            }
        },500);
```

Im very certain that it went into the if, but the video is not played.

Can't figure out why it is not working.

Please help, THANK YOU!

Comment: does the element exist whether or not the video can play? Maybe what is happening is the video is not loaded yet, but `document.getElementById()` is returning an element and is therefore not null, causing the interval to be cleared before the video is loaded.

Comment: i did try to load the video first and used the setInterval, yet the video is still not play. It just seems like .play() is not working in setInterval or setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative, you could try using `readyState`, as:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if( video.readyState === 4) {
    // 4 -> HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA
    //Enough data is available, the media can be played through to the end without interruption.
    video.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case I suggest one of the two following potential solutions:
If you always want it to play right away, do:

```
video.autoplay = true;
```

or you could use `readyState`:

```
var autoplay = setInterval(function(){
        var video = document.getElementById('extVideo-tab1');
        if(video.readyState === 4)
        {
            video.play();
            clearInterval(autoplay);
        }
    },500);
```

Comment: tried autoplay and readyState not working, I'm very certain that play is not working inside setInterval

Comment: are you sure `extVideo-tab1` is an id?

Comment: yes, im very sure. If i place the play outside the setInterval it will play, but not inside setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you cant use the autoplay attribute? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Regardless you should use the onloadedmetadata event or similar that way you know when you can start playing or seek to a point (unless im missing something?)

```
document.getElementById('extVideo-tab1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    this.play();
}, false)
```

Comment: i had already tried with the autoplay attribute, is not working. It might be because im using it in application. What I'm certain off now is that play function wont work inside setInterval or setTimeout.